# Pig ParquetLoader : Column Pruning

Tags: apache-pig, parquet

I read parquet files which has a schema of 12 columns.
I do a group by and sum aggregation over a single long column.
then join on another dataset. after join I only take a single column (the sum one) from the parquet dataset.

But pig constantly keeps on giving me error=>
"ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2000: Error processing rule ColumnMapKeyPrune. Try -t ColumnMapKeyPrune"

Does the pig parquet loader doesn't support column pruning?
If i tried with column pruning disabled, the job works.
pseudo code for what I am trying to achieve.

```
REGISTER /<path>/parquet*.jar;
res1 = load '<path>' using parquet.pig.ParquetLoader() as (c1:chararray,c2:chararray,c3:int, c4:int, c5:chararray, c6:chararray, c7:chararray, c8:chararray, c9:chararray, c10:chararray, c11:chararray, c12:long);
res2 = group winrate  by (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11);
res3 = foreach res2 generate flatten(group) as (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11),SUM(res1.c12) as counts;
```

Comment: hey, did you solve this problem?

Comment: I actually ended up disabling ColumnMapKeyPrune pruning.